# Unix directory for all users permissions

Tags: linux, directory, chmod

I'm trying to make a directory where all users can write, but no user can delete another users file in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

You want a directory where the `t`-bit is set, such as `/tmp`/, `/var/tmp`.

In the [`chmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) manual page, this is referred to as the "sticky bit":

> The restricted deletion flag or sticky bit is a single bit, whose interpretation depends on the file type. For directories, it prevents unprivileged users from removing or renaming a file in the directory unless they own the file or the directory; this is called the restricted deletion flag for the directory, and is commonly found on world-writable directories like /tmp.